# Java Serializing Objects Like an Area

Tags: java, serialization, area

I have read a little bit about 3rd party serialization methods such as JSON, but was wondering if there is any other way to serialize objects such as an area that do not implement serializable. In other word would JSON be the best way to serialize such an object?

EDIT : Throwing A NotSerializable Exception

```
public class Test {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pojo pojo = new Pojo(new Area()); // The original object, NOT SERIALIZABLE !
    byte[] pojoBytes = Serializer.serialize(pojo); // Serialize
    pojo = (Pojo) Serializer.deserialize(pojoBytes); // Deserialize
    System.out.println(pojo); // Good as new !
}

} 

public class Pojo implements Serializable {
private final Area msg;
public Pojo(Area msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
public Area getMsg() {
    return msg;
}
public String toString() {
    return "Pojo says : " + msg;
}
}

public class Serializer {

public static byte[] serialize(Object o) throws Exception {
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Test.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new SurrogateObjectOutputStream(fileOut); // Magically handle Pojos !
oos.writeObject(o);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Test.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    Object o = ois.readObject();
    bais.close();
    return o;
}

}

public class SurrogateObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

public SurrogateObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    super(out);
    enableReplaceObject(true);
}

protected SurrogateObjectOutputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
    super();
    enableReplaceObject(true);
}

@Override
protected Object replaceObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
    if (obj instanceof Pojo) {
        return new PojoSurrogate((Pojo) obj);
    } else return super.replaceObject(obj);
}

}

public class PojoSurrogate implements Serializable {

private Area foo;

public PojoSurrogate(Pojo pojo) {
    this.foo = pojo.getMsg();
}   

private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
    return new Pojo(foo);
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644172/serialize-a-java-awt-geom-area

Comment: @Guy Bouallet Thanks is there anyway you can explain why this works instead of just specifying Shape s = new Area();. Is it because shape is serializable and this method casts an area to a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, if you want to use that `Object` in another program or another language for that matter, then *yes* JSON is the way to go (or XML).

But if you want to reuse that `Object` in another JAVA program then I guess it would be more convenient to look for a way to make possible *non*-serializable `Objects` serializable.

I haven't tested it yet, but I found a promising solution in [this blog (which is in French, sorry)](http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2011/05/07/Serializing-non-serializable-objects). I'll try my best to summarize it:

**what you have**

say you have a class names `Pojo` and you want to serialize it although you don't know if it is serializable or not.

```
public final class Pojo {

    private final String msg;

    public Pojo(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo says : " + msg;
    }
}
```

**what you need**

what you need is a new class that acts as a *surrogate*, which will take the member variables of the *real* `Pojo` and simply *replace* it.

```
public class PojoSurrogate implements Serializable {

    private String foo;

    public PojoSurrogate(Pojo pojo) {
        this.foo = pojo.getMsg();
    }   

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return new Pojo(foo);
    } 
}
```

the last method ( `readResolve()` ) is the one that will in the end give you back your new `Pojo` later.

The other thing you need is your own *surrogate* version of the `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
public class SurrogateObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public SurrogateObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
        enableReplaceObject(true);
    }

    protected SurrogateObjectOutputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super();
        enableReplaceObject(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object replaceObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj instanceof Pojo) {
            return new PojoSurrogate((Pojo) obj);
        } else return super.replaceObject(obj);
    } 
}
```

And again here the last method `replaceObject()` will do the magic and transform the `Pojo` into the serializable version `PojoSurrogate` to store all the information as bytes.

**Serialize like this**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new SurrogateObjectOutputStream(baos); 
oos.writeObject(o);
oos.flush();
oos.close();

byte[] serializedPojo = baos.toByteArray();
```

**Deserialize normally**

```
ObjectInputStream bais = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream( serializedPojo ));
Pojo myNewPojo = (Pojo) bais.readObject();
bais.close();
```

Sorry, long answer.. and I hope I haven't missed anything supercool from that blog where it is easier to create a more scalable solution.. hope this helps anyway!

**[EDIT:]**

I tried your code with an Area object and here is how I got some thing to work (although I am not sure if this is actually working with all `Areas`, so you might have to test if your areas still have the same characteristics after deserialization)

**AreaSurrogate**

```
public class AreaSurrogate implements Serializable {

    private final Rectangle bounds;

    public AreaSurrogate(Area area) {
        this.bounds = area.getBounds();
    }

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return new Area(bounds);
    }
}
```

**SurrogateOutputStream**

```
public class SurrogateOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public SurrogateOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
        enableReplaceObject(true);
    }

    protected SurrogateOutputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super();
        enableReplaceObject(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object replaceObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj instanceof Area) {
            return new AreaSurrogate((Area) obj);
        } else {
            return super.replaceObject(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

**Serializer**

```
public class Serializer {

    public static byte[] serialize(Object o) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new SurrogateOutputStream(baos); // Magically handle Pojos !
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        bais.close();
        return o;
    }
}
```

**Main (to test)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Area area = new Area(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)); // The original object, NOT SERIALIZABLE !
    System.out.println(area.contains(new Rectangle(1, 1, 10, 10))); // Good as new !
    System.out.print("serializing...");
    byte[] pojoBytes = Serializer.serialize(area); // Serialize
    System.out.println("done");
    System.out.print("deserializing...");
    area = (Area) Serializer.deserialize(pojoBytes); // Deserialize
    System.out.println("done");
    System.out.println(area.contains(new Rectangle(1, 1, 10, 10))); // Good as new !
}
```

In the `main()` I create an `Area` from a `Rectangle` which starts at Coordinate (0,0) and is 100 wide and 100 high. Then I test if the Rectangle from (1,1) with 10 width and 10 height is inside the area (which it is, forcibly). After serializing and deserializing I test if the same Rectangle is still inside the new `Area`.

This might be insufficient, since the new `Area` Object is created from a `Rectangle` (see `AreaSurrogate`). so this might not work with other Area shapes..

**expected output**

```
true
serializing...done
deserializing...done
true
```

Comment: How would I go about implementing this for an area specifically? Does this make all objects in java serializable period or is there some exceptions?

Comment: AFAIK, it should make all objects serializable.  So it should work with `Area` Objects, too, although I haven't tested it, sorry. But I don't see why any Object shouldn't be representable as `bytes`. The trick is to tell Java that those bytes can be restructured as an Object. So the most important part is that your surrogate class has the `readResolve()` method and `implements Serializable`. Everything else seems to be less important. I would like to try this with `Area` Objects tomorrow. But maybe you found an answer until then :)

Comment: Thanks loads. This makes it to where I can maintain control of my program using pure java.

Comment: I am getting a NotSerializableException I edited my question with code, but it all seems to be written correctly.

Comment: Retested using the french version it worked with the string. Tested it with Area and got a NotSerializable Exception. Reposting the Area version. I dont know what to do now. It would make sense that it would be serializable but apparently not?

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder: have a look at my edit in the answer. I tried your code and got at least some of it to work