# NotSerializableException with java.awt.geom.Area

Tags: java, awt, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm creating a game where all locations of 'blocks' are stored in the variable `block_area` - an object of class `Area`. My game has been running correctly for a week now, and I've decided to implement a save and load feature where I save `block_area` to a file `Drifter`, with this as my code:

```
Area block_area; // Later initialized

void saveArea()
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savefile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(block_area);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void loadArea()
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(savefile);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        
        block_area  = (Area)ois.readObject();
        
        ois.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, this is my very first time writing and reading an OBJECT to a file, so I don't know much about it. When I try to save the object to the file, it gives me this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.geom.Area
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at Drifter.saveArea(Drifter.java:58)
    at Drifter.keyPressed(Drifter.java:315)
    ...
```

If anyone can tell me how I can go about writing and reading an object with a file, the help will be greatly appreciated.

## TL;DR How do I write the contents of an `Area` object to a file and read it?

**ALSO** I have a few follow-up questions:

- Is `ObjectInputStream` the best course of action here? I have seen a few answers where people recommend using `XML`, and `JSON`, but I can never find the time to learn about them, and would prefer to stick to a pure Java method (without any third party tools)
- Is there any other method of saving an object's information to an external source that I can use instead of file handling?

**EDIT** - I should also mention that my class implements `Serializable`

Comment: *"people recommend using XML .. but I .. would prefer to stick to a pure Java method"* The J2SE has built-in support for reading and writing XML. See also [How to serialize Java 2D Shape objects as XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579729/how-to-serialize-java-2d-shape-objects-as-xml)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson The thing is, I know nothing about XML, and while usually I'd be in the mood to learn new stuff, this is a simple side project that I don't want to invest too much time in

Comment: *"I don't want to invest too much time in"* I can relate to that. Moving along ..

Answer (score 2):

The exception is pretty self explanatory `NotSerializableException: java.awt.geom.Area` .  Any object that you want to serialize must implement the `Serializable` interface.  `java,awt.geom.Area` does not.  Any attributes of that class must also implement Serializable, be a primitive,  or be defined as transient.

I'd suggest either Figuring out a way to read Area into an object that does implement `Serializable`.  When you read it back out, you can construct a new Area object.  This is probably what the [JSON/XML method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579729/how-to-serialize-java-2d-shape-objects-as-xml) mentioned in the comments is doing.  The added benefit of a human readable storage format is that you can edit it in a text editor.  You won't be able to do that with the binary output of a serialized object`.

Comment: _"I'd suggest either Figuring out a way to read Area into an object that does implement Serializable"_ I am aware of this, and have tried making a class `MA` extending `Area` and implementing `Serializable`, but to no avail.

Comment: As for the readability part, it's unnecessary because `block_area` will be generated almost randomly, and reading it is of no use to me

Comment: However, +1 from me for the time you put into this, and it's probably my fault for being too lazy to learn something new like JSOn right now :)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644172/serialize-a-java-awt-geom-area